# UPDATE IF condition before committing

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there an `UPDATE IF` like statement in SQL which allows me to validate a subset of client supplied attributes against the row that needs to be updated?

e.g. `UPDATE posts SET body = $body WHERE post_id = $post_id IF author_id = $author_id`

`FIND`, check, and `UPDATE` wrapped in a transaction isn't as elegant as I would like. Neither is validating client supplied fields by way of the `WHERE` clause.

Adding attributes to the `WHERE` clause will increase the number of indexes that need to be created for no benefit outside of validation.

Comment: I don't get it. What do you expect `IF author_id = $author_id` to do differently than `WHERE author_id = $author_id`?

Comment: That makes it even more confusing. How do you think that strange `IF` feature would be faster if no index is present than a `WHERE` clause? Indexes are created precisely for that reason: speed up data retrieval. Plus: you should have an index on `author_id` anyways because I suspect that to be a foreign key to an `author` table.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this?

```
  UPDATE posts 
   SET body = $body 
   WHERE post_id   = $post_id AND 
         author_id = $author_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use the IF condition in the WHERE-clause directly?

```
UPDATE posts
SET body = $body
WHERE post_id = $post_id
AND author_id = $author_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not an `IF` clause available in `UPDATE` in *Postgres*.

Here's the *Postgres* doc containing the grammar for [UPDATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html).

While I know you mentioned you didn't find it as elegant, you would need to include the items to be validated in the `WHERE` clause.

Another option, although you'd still need to include it in the `WHERE` clause, would be to encapsulate the validation logic in a *pl/pgSQL* function. If you had the exact same validation logic that you needed in a bunch of queries, that might be a cleaner way to centralize the logic and reduce duplication within the queries.